# how to fix error in std::vector<int> WidthNumbers = 320, 640, 1280;?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

So I try to do something like   `std::vector<int> WidthNumbers = 320, 640, 1280;` but compiler gives me error `C2440: 'int' to 'std::vector<_Ty>'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot initialize a `vector` using that syntax. C++0x allows initializer lists which allow you to use the following:

```
std::vector<int> WidthNumbers = {320, 640, 1280};
```

But this has not been implemented in VS2010. The alternatives are:

```
int myArr[] = {320, 640, 1280};
std::vector<int> WidthNumbers( myArr, myArr + sizeof(myArr) / sizeof(myArr[0]) );
```

**OR**

```
std::vector<int> WidthNumbers;

WidthNumbers.push_back(320);
WidthNumbers.push_back(640);
WidthNumbers.push_back(1280);
```

Comment: When using the first option, the following template is useful: `template <typename T, size_t N> T* endof(T (&ra)[N]) { return ra+N; }`. It returns the same pointer that C++0x's `std::end` does for an array, and it means that the second line becomes `std::vector<int> WidthNumbers(myArr, endof(myArr));`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [boost::assign::list_of](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#list_of)

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

#include <vector>

int
main()
{
    typedef std::vector<int> WidthNumbers;
    const WidthNumbers foo = boost::assign::list_of(320)(640)(1280);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your compiler supports C++0x (MSVC++2010 has [partial support for C++0x](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport)) you can use an [initializer list](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#init-list)

```
std::vector<int> WidthNumbers = {320, 640, 1280};
```

Comment: However, VC++ 2010's partial support does *not* include this feature.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly more work, but I find it works very well with VS 2010. Instead of using an Initializer List, you can manually add items to the vector using the `_vector.push_back()` method like so:

```
//forward declarations
#include <vector>  
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// main() function
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR *argv)
{
     // declare vector
     vector<int> _vector;
     // fill vector with items
     _vector.push_back(1088);
     _vector.push_back(654);
     _vector.push_back(101101);
     _vector.push_back(123456789);
     // iterate through the vector and print items to the console
     vector<int>::iterator iter = _vector.begin();
     while(iter != _vector.end())
     {
          cout << *iter << endl;
          iter++;
     }
     // pause so you can read the output
     system("PAUSE");
     // end program
     return 0;
 }
```

This is the way I personally declare and initialize vectors, it always works for me